# get a particular host name's ip with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have a host file that looks roughly like this:

```
[kibanamaster]
efk host_ip host user passwd
[elasticnode]
esnode host_ip user passwd
```

and I am trying something in the style of

```
- name: get ip address node1
  debug: var=hostvars[inventory_host]['esnode']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] 
  register: es_node1
```

But I get variable not defined. Anyone outthere able to help?

EDIT: 
If I do

```
debug: var=hostvars[LOG1]['esnode']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
register: node_1
```

I get

`{"hostvars[LOG1]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pre-loaded ansible variable to get values for both ipv4, ipv6 & hostname

```
IPV4 --> {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}

IPV6 --> {{ ansible_eth0.ipv6.address }}

Hostname --> {{ ansible_hostname }
```

Comment: Of course, this will only work if you have an `eth0`.

Answer (score 8):

`hostvars` [magic variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) is a dictionary with keys named after hosts in your inventory.

So you may want to try:

```
hostvars['esnode']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
```

to get ip address of `esnode` host.

Comment: OK I take it back - it does not work -
     hostvars[LOG1]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Comment: What is `LOG1` here?

Comment: LOG1 is a machine, but the point is that the moment i register that variable - I get an ugli long text in the configuration file I have rather than just the IP.

Comment: Ensure that `LOG1` is defined, and facts has been gathered for this host before the point in time when you try to fetch ip address from hostvars.